# Should I connect to QNetworkReply::error() as well?

Tags: c++, qt, qtnetwork

I have created a POST request and I connect to the [finished()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtnetwork/qnetworkreply.html#finished) signal:

```
QNetworkReply *reply = manager->post(request, postData.encodedQuery());
connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(accept()));
```

I want to be notified when the POST request has finished, regardless of whether it failed or succeeded.

I have noticed in the documentation that there is also a [QNetworkReply::error()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtnetwork/qnetworkreply.html#error-2) signal, do I need to connect to it, too, or will `finished()` be called in all cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt documentation states:

> void QNetworkReply::error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError code) [signal]
>
> This signal is emitted when the reply detects an error in processing. 
>   The finished()     signal will probably follow, indicating that 
>   the connection is over.

From what I've seen in Qt sources (was checking absolutely same issue recently), everywhere after error(), there is a finished() call afterwards. In 5.1.0 I haven't found a place where error is not followed by finished()

for example

```
void QNetworkReplyImpl::close()
{
    Q_D(QNetworkReplyImpl);
    if (d->state == QNetworkReplyImplPrivate::Aborted ||
        d->state == QNetworkReplyImplPrivate::Finished)
        return;

    // stop the download
    if (d->backend)
        d->backend->closeDownstreamChannel();
    if (d->copyDevice)
        disconnect(d->copyDevice, 0, this, 0);

    QNetworkReply::close();

    // call finished which will emit signals
    d->error(OperationCanceledError, tr("Operation canceled"));
    d->finished();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for `error()` says, "the `finished()` signal will probably follow", so no, `finished()` ought to be sufficient. Don't forget to check the `error()` getter in the signal handler, though.

Comment: I was wondering about the "probably" part mostly. It was pretty ambiguous. They don't say it's a sure thing.

Comment: True, that is kind of suspicious. In your place, I would start reading the Qt source to understand where `error()` is triggered and find out whether that would ever prevent `finished()` from being triggered too. That's the nice thing when you have the source, and Qt is more readable than most things I know.