# When will QNetworkReply::error signal followed by a finished() signal?

Tags: c++, qt

For the signal:

```
QNetworkReply::error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError code)
```

Qt's documentation said:

> This signal is emitted when the reply detects an error in processing.
>   The finished() signal will probably follow, indicating that the
>   connection is over.

To be specific, when will the finished() signal be emitted and when not?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404483/should-i-connect-to-qnetworkreplyerror-as-well) might answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When will QNetworkReply::error signal followed by a finished() signal?
>   To be specific, when will the finished() signal be emitted and when
>   not?

Signal `finished()` is emitted when request is finished either due to data transmission complete or an error during transmission. Signal `error()` is happening right before `finished()` in case of an error. In practice we can handle `finished()` for both "error" and "transmission successful".

To illustrate:

```
// connect 'finished' signal with consumer
connect(&s_networkAccessManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
        this, SLOT(requestFinished(QNetworkReply*)));



void MyClass::requestFinished(QNetworkReply* pReply)
{
    if ( pReply )
    {
         if (pReply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
             consumeData(pReply)
         else
             errorHandler(pReply->error(), pReply->errorString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. My worry is that, is it possible that "reply actually already finished due to error and no more contents will be read in, but finished() signal is not emited" ?

Comment: @Nyaruko In practice we are satisfied with such handler. We also connect QNetworkReply::sslErrors signal returned by networkAccessManager.post().

Comment: for my case, I am just downloading some files (some of them might be large, say 100MB) through normal http. Will it necessary to worry about the sslErrors? And what version of Qt are you using?

Comment: We started with Qt 5.3 and now on Qt 5.5. Of course sslErrors is needed for https and is happening mostly during fist post or get attempt. We deal with security.

Comment: So, for plain http no need to worry about the sslErros? I am just writing small programs for testing.

Comment: No only https needs sslErrors.